# Terraform template with multiple IPs for a same variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform output like this

```
output  "servers_private_ip"{
    value = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myservers_vm.*.private_ip_address
}
```

```
servers_private_ip = [
  "10.0.2.7",
  "10.0.2.5",
  "10.0.2.8",
]
```

I need to render these as below into a variable that can be used in a `.tpl` file

```
10.0.2.7:1245,10.0.2.5:1245,10.0.2.8:1245
```

i tried it like this

```
tpl_variable = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myservers_vm.*.private_ip_address
```

But i am not sure how can i append the port number i want for each ip in this,Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

`join` the list items where each item has port appended:

```
tpl_variable = join(",", [for ip in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myservers_vm.*.private_ip_address: "${ip}:1245"])
```